# Mostrar ValidationError en el template - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Estoy realizando un programa que consta de ventas.

Quiero que al registrar una venta, si no hay suficiente stock del producto solicitado, salga un error indicando que no hay stock.

Pude hacerlo pero me sale el ValidationError asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora paso a dejar el form que hice y la view:

forms.py:

```
class VentasForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Formulario modelo de ventas."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""
        model = Venta
        fields = ('fecha', 'cliente', 'producto', 'cantidad', 'forma_pago')

    def save(self):
        """Restar stock."""
        data = super().clean()

        producto = Product.objects.get(id=data['producto'].pk)
        verificar_stock = producto.cantidad - float(data['cantidad'])
        if verificar_stock >= 0:
            producto.cantidad -= float(self.data['cantidad'])
            producto.save()
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('No hay suficiente stock del producto.')
```

views.py:

```
class CreateVentasView(CreateView):
    """Registrar venta."""

template_name = 'ventas/create.html'
form_class = VentasForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('ventas:list')
context_object_name = 'venta'
```

Y el template solo esta hecho con un `{{ form.as_p }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debia agregar un return al final de la funcion save y agregar una funcion clean.

Dejo el codigo:

```
def clean(self):
    """Verificar si hay stock del producto."""
    data = super().clean()

    producto = Product.objects.get(id=data['producto'].pk)
    if producto.cantidad < float(self.data['cantidad']):
        raise forms.ValidationError('No hay suficiente stock del producto.')
    return data

def save(self):
    """Restar stock."""
    data = self.cleaned_data

    producto = Product.objects.get(id=data['producto'].pk)

    producto.cantidad -= float(data['cantidad'])
    producto.save()

    return super().save()
```